# Redmine rake tasks failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake, redmine

Posting on SO as looks like a rubygems issue. I am trying to run a rake task in cronjob of my redmine installation but it fails with error gem not found. Below are the logs:

```
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find i18n-0.6.11 in any of the sources
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:94:in `block in materialize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `map!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `materialize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:137:in `specs'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:182:in `specs_for'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:171:in `requested_specs'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:92:in `setup'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/redmine-2.6.3/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/redmine-2.6.3/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/redmine-2.6.3/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
```

Now I am not quite sure as to why is `i18n-0.6.11` not found as I have installed it globally too(using rvm). Also the gemset being used is showing as `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems` which is different from my gems directory. Installation details are:

Redmine installation Directory: ~/redmine
RubyGems directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using rvm for ruby version management but I had also installed ruby form ubuntu sources and the cron executing rake tasks was using system installed ruby. So the solution was to run:
`rvm cron setup`

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute `bundle install` in redmine directory and then try to start redmine server again.

Comment: Did that but to no avail